# How to prevent a Discord bot from going offline when I close the SSH tab?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, discord, discord.js

I hosted my bot in GCP so it will be 24/7 online and when I start the bot by using the SSH browser it starts normally but when I close the SSH tab my bot goes automatically offline. what's the solution behind this? My bot has no errors at all + I tried hosting it in repl.it and it works fine.

Comment: Are you using a process manager such as [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)?

Comment: Already got a solution to this but thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a process manager like [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/). You can install it using NPM:

```
npm i -g pm2
```

That may require you to use `sudo`. After installation head to your Discord bot's directory and run these commands:

```
pm2 start index.js 

pm2 startup

pm2 save
```

Checkout PM2's [documentation](https://pm2.io/docs/plus/overview/) for detailed information.

Comment: TYSM! works now

Comment: btw how do I stop the "pm2 process"

Comment: @Dissolved you can use `pm2 stop <process_name>` (or go to that directory and `pm2 stop index.js` if you had specified file name). `pm2 delete` can be used to delete the process. If my answer was helpful, consider accepting it by clicking the tick icon :)